# Getting full name of file after scp - batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scp

Hello I'm trying to make a simple .bat file, I'm trying to modify a file after downloading it from another machine.

The problem is the python script needs the full name of the file, so filename* won't work so is there a way to download a file via scp and then somehow assign the downloaded file a variable so the script can find the full name

scp user@192.168.1.X:"C:\Users\user\Downloads\filename*" ./

pythonscript.py filename*

Comment: Download it to a location which holds no other files. It should be simple to get the name of the only file in a known location.

Answer (score 0):

```
pythonscript.py "%cd%\filename"
```